# Voice recognition text input for Apple Watchkit?

Tags: ios, xcode6, voice-recognition, watchkit, apple-watch

I would like to add a screen where it accepts the user's voice, so I can convert it to a string and make a query request to a remove server. Does Watchkit provide this mechanism to developers? I couldn't find any controls that do this in Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:allowedInputMode:completion:` on WKInterfaceController to do this.

Comment: The only thing is it forces me to supply suggestions, when I want to accept the user's input.

Comment: Unfortunately dictation is not supported in the simulator. You'll have to wait and test with hardware. The only support option is to use the suggestions array.

Comment: If you pass `nil` as your suggestions, the Watch will immediately go into dictation mode. For testing, I add a few suggestions if it's a simulator build. Otherwise, for production builds, I pass nil. This does work on an actual device.